# JQUERY: IE9 ignoring PreventDefault

Tags: jquery, asp.net, forms, preventdefault

I've search high and low and turned up with no solution.

I am wanting my submit function to handle the action when the user clicks the submitt button, and override the default action.Firefox and Chrome work flawless, but in IE9, clicking the form button results in the page going to Default.aspx(I am using ASP.NET, and running this code on localhost).

```
/////////////////Submit Function/////////////
 $('#ARBB').submit(function (event) {
     //e.cancelBubble is supported by IE - this will kill the bubbling process.
     event.cancelBubble = true;
     event.returnValue = false;

     //e.stopPropagation works only in Firefox.
     if (event.stopPropagation) {
         event.stopPropagation();
         event.preventDefault();
     }

     // initialize validator for a bunch of input fields
     var inputs = $("#Contact :input").validator();

     // perform validation programmatically
     //inputs.data("validator").checkValidity();

     $('#conf').load("/Confirmation.aspx");

     $.blockUI({ css: {
         border: 'none',
         padding: '15px',
         backgroundColor: '#000',
         '-webkit-border-radius': '10px',
         '-moz-border-radius': '10px',
         opacity: .5,
         color: '#fff'
     }
     });

     setTimeout($.unblockUI, 500);

     $("#accordion").accordion("enable");
     $("#accordion").accordion("option", "active", 3);
     $("#CheckMark3").fadeIn("fast");
     $('html, body').animate({
         scrollTop: $("#Section3").offset().top
     }, 500);

 });
 ///////////////////////////////////////////
```

**EDIT/UPDATE**

IE9 is throwing the error when the load function is called:

$('#conf').load("/Confirmation.aspx");

The error is:

SCRIPT5: Access is denied.

jquery-1.6.2.js, line 6244 character 2

Comment: "//e.stopPropagation works only in Firefox." Say what? I don't know where you get your info from, but it's wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The jQuery library already takes care of the browser differences for you. All you need to handle all different browsers is:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

Comment: @Guffa..I've already tried that. IE9 submits the form and ignores event.preventDefault();

Comment: what about `event.returnValue = false` in IE9?

Comment: @user1265533: The you have some error somewhere else in your code that keeps it from working. It's the correct way of doing it, and trying to do it any other way will not make it any better.

Comment: Thanks, It appears flowplayer's Jquery Validation plugin is not compatible with IE9, even the demos on their site do not work with IE9

Comment: Updates Original post: Could Access denied error be the cause?

Comment: @user1265533: The `returnValue` property only exists in IE, and isn't supported by jQuery, so don't use it. Just use the `preventDefault` method.

Comment: @user1265533: Yes, if an access denied error crashes the code, that would keep the code from stopping the event.

Answer (score 1):

did you tried entering return false at the end of the method?

```
$('#ARBB').submit(function (event) {
     //e.cancelBubble is supported by IE - this will kill the bubbling process.
     event.cancelBubble = true;
     event.returnValue = false;

     //e.stopPropagation works only in Firefox.
     if (event.stopPropagation) {
         event.stopPropagation();
         event.preventDefault();
     }

     // initialize validator for a bunch of input fields
     var inputs = $("#Contact :input").validator();

     // perform validation programmatically
     //inputs.data("validator").checkValidity();

     $('#conf').load("/Confirmation.aspx");

     $.blockUI({ css: {
         border: 'none',
         padding: '15px',
         backgroundColor: '#000',
         '-webkit-border-radius': '10px',
         '-moz-border-radius': '10px',
         opacity: .5,
         color: '#fff'
     }
     });

     setTimeout($.unblockUI, 500);

     $("#accordion").accordion("enable");
     $("#accordion").accordion("option", "active", 3);
     $("#CheckMark3").fadeIn("fast");
     $('html, body').animate({
         scrollTop: $("#Section3").offset().top
     }, 500);
return false;
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

`preventDefault()` just working for fire fox and chrome. 
try thi code:

```
if (event.preventDefault) { event.preventDefault(); } else { event.returnValue = false; }
```

this code checks if browser supports `preventDefault` uses it else executes second part.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the issue was with some CSS code that appears at the top of the page I am loading(Confirmation.aspx). After deleting the css code, I longer get the access denied error.